# Prevent collapsible navbar from wrapping under an image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to prevent the collapsed navbar from wrapping under the image. Once the resolution is less than 476px the navbar wraps. I tried using d-sm-inline-block in my `<nav>` tag but it continues to wrap.

I attached an image showing what the code is exactly doing. I also removed the image I am using from the code because I am building this in a Django Template.

Using Bootstrap4

[image: navbar wrapping]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">

    <img class="img-fluid picture-padding" src="temp" alt="temp">

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the context of your question correctly it looks like you are attempting to add a logo to a responsive bootstrap 4 based template. If my assumption is correct replacing the following line:

```
<img class="img-fluid picture-padding" src="temp" alt="temp">
```

With:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="temp" width="30" height="30" alt="">
</a>
```

Should accomplish what you're looking for.

Here is the full bootstrap 4 template page code used:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>   -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="./test.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the mobile result:

[image: mobile bootstrap navigation bar with branding]

Here is the desktop result:

[image: desktop bootstrap navigation bar with branding]